# can Syncfusion.Pdf.WinForms nuget package be used for free?

Tags: winforms, pdf, edit, syncfusion

Create, Read and Edit PDF file in Windows Forms using Syncfusion PDF library

Referenced url address:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Pdf.WinForms/

Comment: Questions about licensing are off-topic. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing

Answer (score 2):

Greetings !!!

You can download the Syncfusion.Pdf.WinForms (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Pdf.WinForms/) NuGet package from nuget.org and use it for their development. But, the license message will pop up when launching the application. Because Syncfusion introduced the licensing system from v16.2.0.41 only for Syncfusion NuGet packages and evaluation setup. You also need to generate the license key (not unlock key) and register it when the launch of your application as specified in the below help documents if referring the assemblies from Syncfusion NuGet packages or from the evaluation setup.

https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/licensing/license-key

Also, please refer to the below blog post for understanding the licensing changes introduced in Essential Studio.

https://blog.syncfusion.com/post/whats-new-in-2018-volume-2-licensing-changes-in-the-1620x-version-of-essential-studio.aspx

Refer to the below help link to know what nuget.org users to do if they don’t have a Syncfusion account.

https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/licensing/license-key#nugetorg-users-without-a-syncfusion-account

Regards,

Vadivel Natarajan